# How to have multiple instances of the same Vue JS component with vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue component that is instantiated multiple times on the page with different data in each instance. I want the routes for these components to act independently of each other, where clicking a button in one of the instances will move to the next view for only that instance. However, it is not like that, and clicking the button changes the view in all component instances. Is there some sort of configuration I can use to achieve this?

This `init` function is called multiple times on the page, with a different ID and different video object.

```
export function init(id, video, hotElementId) {
  const element = `#${hotElementId}`

  new Vue({
    el: element,
    store,
    router,
    data: () => {
      return {
        id: id
      }
    },
    template: '<MonetizationGate/>',
    components: { MonetizationGate },
    beforeMount: function () {
      // set the video object in the store
      store.commit({
        type: 'setVideoObject',
        video: video,
        id: id
      })
    },
    render: h => h(MonetizationGate)
  })
}
```

My routing set up:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Gate,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: Subscribe
      },
      {
        path: '/sign_in',
        component: SignIn
      }
    ]
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes
})
```

Comment: How do those links look like? Have you tried using [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching)?

Comment: show us some snippet code to be more clear

Comment: Updated the post with some code around how my component gets initialized and the routing.

Comment: i don't understand the pattern that you follow, why do you create multiple vue instances?

Comment: Each instance gets tied to a different div ID. I'd like each instance to be independent. Sort of like a widget.

Comment: are you working with vue cli 3 or just using CDN?

Comment: working with the cli

Comment: you could create one vue instance and multiple components and jump between them using the router